# SQL advanced query - problem with single row aggregate sub query in select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to execute the following query but I receive a runtime error stating that:

```
"The column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
```

Line number two below is the one that fails with the error above. I don't understand why this query doesn't execute as no grouping should be required in line two as the output is just count(*), any clue as to what I need to change to get this working?

```
SELECT @lessonPlans = COUNT(*)
, @lessonPlanResources = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.LessonPlanResource lpr where lpr.LessonPlanId = a.LessonPlanId )
FROM
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT lpt.LessonPlanId
    FROM dbo.LearningTargetBreakout ltb
    JOIN dbo.LessonPlanLearningTarget lpt 
        on lpt.LearningTargetId = ltb.LearningTargetId
    WHERE (CASE 
            WHEN ltb.LearningTargetId = @learningTargetId and @learningTargetId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.CategoryId = @categoryId and @categoryId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.Grade = @grade and @grade is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.SubjectId = @subjectId and @subjectId is not null THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END) = 1
) a
```

**[Edit]**

Using a slight variation of Zeb's solution - here is the revised code that I ended up using, which yields one row with aggregates, which is what I was after.

```
SELECT @lessonPlans = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0)
        , @lessonPlanResources = ISNULL(SUM(a.ResCount), 0)
FROM
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT lpt.LessonPlanId, lpr.ResCount
    FROM dbo.LearningTargetBreakout ltb
    JOIN dbo.LessonPlanLearningTarget lpt 
        on lpt.LearningTargetId = ltb.LearningTargetId
    JOIN (SELECT LessonPlanId, COUNT(*) ResCount FROM dbo.LessonPlanResource lpr GROUP BY LessonPlanId) lpr
        ON lpr.LessonPlanId = lpt.LessonPlanId          
    WHERE (CASE 
            WHEN ltb.LearningTargetId = @learningTargetId and @learningTargetId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.CategoryId = @categoryId and @categoryId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.GradeId = @grade and @grade is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.SubjectId = @subjectId and @subjectId is not null THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END) = 1
) a
```

Comment: whats your reason behind doing a count(*) and not count(lpr.lessionplanid)

Comment: Since the output of the inner query in the from clause is just the LessonPlanId field it is actually the same as typing out count(lpr.lessionplanid) if i'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that the @lessonPlanResources is linked to the LessonPlanId, which is not aggregate.

My solution would be to JOIN to that subtable, and have the returned column be a COUNT of it.

```
SELECT @lessonPlans = COUNT(*)
, @lessonPlanResources = SUM(zlpr.reses)
FROM
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT lpt.LessonPlanId, zlpr.reses
    FROM dbo.LearningTargetBreakout ltb
    JOIN dbo.LessonPlanLearningTarget lpt 
        on lpt.LearningTargetId = ltb.LearningTargetId
    JOIN (SELECT LessonPlanId, COUNT(*) reses FROM dbo.LessonPlanResource lpr) zlpr
        ON zlpr.LessonPlanId = lpt.LessonPlanId
    WHERE (CASE 
            WHEN ltb.LearningTargetId = @learningTargetId and @learningTargetId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.CategoryId = @categoryId and @categoryId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.Grade = @grade and @grade is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.SubjectId = @subjectId and @subjectId is not null THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END) = 1
) a
```

Comment: Nice moves, this was the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 3):

Your `count(*)` is an aggregate function and the expression for @lessonPlanResources is not (even though it's a query with `COUNT(*)`).  Therefore, the expression must be included in the GROUP BY clause.

You can use common table expressions(CTE), which may help with readability too.

```
WITH LPR_CTE as
    (
    SELECT LessonPlanId, COUNT(*) as LessonPlanResourcesCount
    FROM dbo.LessonPlanResource
    GROUP BY LessonPlanId
    ),

    LP_CTE(
    SELECT lpt.LessonPlanId, COUNT(*) as LessonPlansCount
    FROM dbo.LearningTargetBreakout ltb
    JOIN dbo.LessonPlanLearningTarget lpt 
        on lpt.LearningTargetId = ltb.LearningTargetId
    WHERE (CASE 
            WHEN ltb.LearningTargetId = @learningTargetId and @learningTargetId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.CategoryId = @categoryId and @categoryId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.Grade = @grade and @grade is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.SubjectId = @subjectId and @subjectId is not null THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END) = 1
    )

SELECT @lessonPlans = LP_CTE.LessonPlansCount
     , @lessonPlanResources = LPR_CTE.LessonPlanResourcesCount
FROM LP_CTE
JOIN LPR_CTE on LP_CTE.LessonPlanId = LPR_CTE.LessonPlanId
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to `GROUP BY a.LessonPlanId` and possibly change the first `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(*) OVER()` depending on what exactly you are trying to do.

But that will presumably give multiple rows of results that you are then trying to assign to a single set of scalar variables. What *are* you trying to do exactly?

Comment: +1 Adding a group by to the end of the outer query as you suggested seems to fix the problem. But logically i'm just not seeing how that makes any sense. Is this just one of those vendor specific gotcha's?

Comment: @James - MySQL doesn't enforce this but all others do. I think you're still going to have a problem though with trying to get multiple rows into the scalar variable though (I guess you're probably just going to end up with them holding the value of the last group processed)

Comment: My intent was to only fetch aggregates into the variables not rows.

Comment: @James - If you run your query just as a straightforward `SELECT` without the assignment to variables you should see multiple rows (one for each LessonPlanId). Whichever one ends up in the variable at the end will be arbitrary  and just depend in which order the groups were processed. I doubt that can be the intention?

Comment: You're correct, I think i'll need to completely rethink my strategy on this one...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using a grouping function (count) with this subquery:SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.LessonPlanResource lpr where lpr.LessonPlanId = a.LessonPlanId

However the reference to a.LessonPlanId is a non-grouped field.  Group your query and you can reference that field.

Try this:

```
SELECT @lessonPlans = COUNT(*)
, @lessonPlanResources = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.LessonPlanResource lpr where lpr.LessonPlanId = a.LessonPlanId )
FROM
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT lpt.LessonPlanId
    FROM dbo.LearningTargetBreakout ltb
    JOIN dbo.LessonPlanLearningTarget lpt 
        on lpt.LearningTargetId = ltb.LearningTargetId
    WHERE (CASE 
            WHEN ltb.LearningTargetId = @learningTargetId and @learningTargetId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.CategoryId = @categoryId and @categoryId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.Grade = @grade and @grade is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.SubjectId = @subjectId and @subjectId is not null THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END) = 1
) a
GROUP BY a.LessonPlanID
```

Comment: Thanks, does this suggest that I no longer need to do the distinct in the inner query of the from clause where I expect dups?

Comment: No it would not be necessary as any dupes would be eliminated by the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

- Removing the COUNT from your outer select.
- Using COUNT DISTINCT in your inner select

---

```
SELECT 
   @lessonPlans = a.B,
   @lessonPlanResources = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.LessonPlanResource lpr where lpr.LessonPlanId = a.LessonPlanId )
FROM
( 
    SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT, lpt.LessonPlanId) AS B
    FROM dbo.LearningTargetBreakout ltb
    JOIN dbo.LessonPlanLearningTarget lpt 
        on lpt.LearningTargetId = ltb.LearningTargetId
    WHERE (CASE 
            WHEN ltb.LearningTargetId = @learningTargetId and @learningTargetId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.CategoryId = @categoryId and @categoryId is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.Grade = @grade and @grade is not null THEN 1
            WHEN ltb.SubjectId = @subjectId and @subjectId is not null THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END) = 1
) a
```